# Lodash for reagrup complex Array[object]

Tags: arrays, underscore.js, lodash

### I'm a newbie but i thing this is for Senior Lodash Programmer

I'm new to Lodash and trying to solve this problem but could find a good way to do it.

I have an array of orders and an array of lines with one ticket into each order.

### The data is structured as below:

```
[{
"id": 201,    
"order": "Buyer 1",  
"lines": ▿[
  ▿{
    "id": 1,        
    "ticket": ▿{
      "id": 151,
      "event": ▿{
        "id": 31,
        "name": "Event 1"           
      },
      "name": "Event 1 Ticket 1",        
      "price": 39,
      "minimum": 1,
      "maximum": 5
    },
    "quantity": 1
  },
  ▿{
    "id": 2,       
    "ticket": {
      "id": 152,
      "event": {
        "id": 31,
        "name": "Event 1"            
      },
      "name": "Event 1 Ticket 2",        
      "price": 60,
      "minimum": 2,
      "maximum": 4
    },
    "quantity": 5
  },
 ▿{
    "id": 3,       
    "ticket": {
      "id": 153,
      "event": {
        "id": 33,
        "name": "Event 1"            
      },
      "name": "Event 3 Ticket 2",        
      "price": 60,
      "minimum": 2,
      "maximum": 4
    },
    "quantity": 5
  }       
],
"created_at": "2016-12-22T17:58:27+0000"
},    
...]
```

### I need to group all orders by event name and need the next structure:

```
[{
 "event_id": 31,
 "event_name":"Event 1",
 "total_tickets": 6,
 "total_sold": 339
 "orders": [
   {
    "id": 201,
    "order": "Buyer 1"  
   },
   ....
 ]},
 {
 "event_id": 33,
 "event_name":"Event 3",
 "total_tickets": 5,
 "total_sold": 300
 "orders":[
    {
     "id": 201,
     "order": "Buyer 1"  
    }                            
  ]},
 ....
]
```

"total_tickets" -> sum of order' tickets (quantity) of event

"total_sold" -> sum of order' (price* quantity) of event

#### Any help will by very usefull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `_.reduce` (or even vainilla JS `Array.reduce`)

As a friendly advice, try to imagine and sketch - in your mind, or a paper - what exactly needs be done with that data and then start looking for the tools to do it, not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks, i created a function that change the structure.